# Windows 8 C#/XAML SuspensionManager failed

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I'm writing simple imageviewer for one imageboard. I'm using these 2 classes for navigation(navigation parameter for `Frame.Navigate()` method) in my app:

```
public class KonaParameter
{
    public int page { get; set; }
    public string tags { get; set; }

    public KonaParameter()
    {
        page = 1;
    }
}

public class Post
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string tags { get; set; }
    public int created_at { get; set; }
    public int creator_id { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
    public int change { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public int score { get; set; }
    public string md5 { get; set; }
    public int file_size { get; set; }
    public string file_url { get; set; }
    public bool is_shown_in_index { get; set; }
    public string preview_url { get; set; }
    public int preview_width { get; set; }
    public int preview_height { get; set; }
    public int actual_preview_width { get; set; }
    public int actual_preview_height { get; set; }
    public string sample_url { get; set; }
    public int sample_width { get; set; }
    public int sample_height { get; set; }
    public int sample_file_size { get; set; }
    public string jpeg_url { get; set; }
    public int jpeg_width { get; set; }
    public int jpeg_height { get; set; }
    public int jpeg_file_size { get; set; }
    public string rating { get; set; }
    public bool has_children { get; set; }
    public object parent_id { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public bool is_held { get; set; }
    public string frames_pending_string { get; set; }
    public List<object> frames_pending { get; set; }
    public string frames_string { get; set; }
    public List<object> frames { get; set; }
    public object flag_detail { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I faced is that suspending doesn't work. SuspensionManager throws "SuspensionManager failed" exception after `await SuspensionManager.SaveAsync();` call(I googled that it's because of using complex types).

I tried to use string as a navigation parameter. It works, but I need more than 1 string for my parameter(`List<string>` doesn't work, I tried to use it).

How to suspend my app correctly?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that SuspensionManager uses Frame.GetNavigationState() to get the history of the Frame. It then tries to serialise the navigation history to a string, unfortunately it has no way to know how to serialise custom complex types as parameters like Post or KonaParameter and fails with an exception.

If you want to use SuspensionManager then you'll need to restrict yourself to simple types like int or string as parameters.

If you do need complex types then it's best to store them in some background service / repository with an identifier. You can then pass the identifier as the parameter.

Answer (score 3):

The recommended approach is to serialize your "state" object, so it can be saved/restored as a string. You can use [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) to do this:

```
//save state
Post post = //...;
string state = JsonConvert.Serialize(post)

//restore state
Post post = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Post>(state);
```

If you want to use two objects (a Post and a KonaParameter), I'd consider creating an "aggregate" class that encapsulates both, and serializing/deserializing that instead:

```
public class State
{
    public Post post {get; set;}
    public KonaParameter param {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sugggesting Json.NET, it made everything easy. I just converted `NavigationParameter`s to a serialized string and problem solved.

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi what do you mean you converted you navigationParameter? I think I may have the same issue as you. I'm saving all my data as strings, but the app still breaks when I put it in suspension.

Comment: @eastbeast I was passing a custom class (containing strings, integers, ...) as `NavigationParameter`. What solved my problem is to send just an string (containing serialized version of that custom class) as `NavigationParameter` and deserialize it in target page.